# words being left out

Tags: python, cpu-word, python-itertools

This program will generate a list of letter combinations and check if they are English words, but the program is leaving some words out, i checked the dictionary file and the words were there but still not in the output, Please tell me why the program is leaving out a lot of results such as `home` `corn` `barn` and so on.

```
import itertools
#http://www.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/engwords.txt

with open('/Users/kyle/Documents/english words.txt') as word_file:
    english_words = set(word.strip().lower() for word in word_file if len(word.strip()) == 4)

for p1 in itertools.combinations('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 4):
    word = ''.join(p1)
    if word in english_words:
        print '{} is {}'.format(word, word in english_words)
```

This is the dictionary that i am using http://www.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/engwords.txt

Comment: you should use `itertools.product` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're  looking for `product` ([Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)), not `combinations` (which won't produce words whose letters aren't in alphabetical order or have duplicate letters):

```
import string

for letters in itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase, repeat=4):
    word = ''.join(letters)

    if word in english_words:
        print word
```

You could also use tuples instead of strings, which should speed this up:

```
import string
from itertools import product
#http://www.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/engwords.txt

with open('/Users/kyle/Documents/english words.txt', 'r') as word_file:
    english_words = set(tuple(word.strip().lower()) for word in word_file if len(word.strip()) == 4)

words = english_words.intersection(product(string.ascii_lowercase, repeat=4))
```